# AMChart implementation for "DateTime" AxisType?

Tags: highcharts, amcharts

I am porting a set of Highchart implementations to Amcharts. In highcharts, there are a set of AxisTypes namely Linear,Logarithmic,Datetime, which determine the number scale of y axes.Found alternatives in Amcharts for Logarithmic and Linear [ValueAxis { logarithmic : true/false }], but unable to find alternative in amcharts for "datetime" axis type.
The following is the effect of setting these axis types for a given set of data:

Linear:
[image]
Logarithmic:
[image]

Datetime
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated..Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the issue that you can't get AmCharts to format datetimes correctly on the ValueAxis?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need to show duration on your ValueAxis, here is an example:

http://www.amcharts.com/demos/duration-on-value-axis/

Answer (score 1):

You can control how the datetimes are displayed on the ValueAxis by implementing your own LabelFunction on the ValueAxis.

See: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis